# Retrieve the creator account name of a new generated account

Tags: accounts, account-name, create

Since anyone has to be invited in the network to create a new account; is possible to get in some way the address(=account name) of the creator?

Comment: What do you mean by address here? Creator has account name not any address.

Comment: The account name is the address on the EOS network. So, yes I want the account name of the cretor of my account.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your account name go [this](http://eosnetworkmonitor.io) site and there is a option called **Account Info**  on the top left corner. Click on that and put your account name. After enter you will find all info , ram and cpu allocation to your account. Now there is a option at top 
*Get accounts transactions history. **History***. click on history and you will get who created your account.

like I find about mine:

```
Block:#14831144,
TXid:1a4f920e0ea6cafb86f2442aa7e3aa320e0d79b9a1feb7eb7babeee936018b98,
Date:2018-09-05 14:54:09,
Action:newaccount,
From:1freeaccount,
Info:
nirdeshkumar
```